# convert struct in_addr to text

Tags: c, sockets

just wondering if I have a struct in_addr,
how do I convert that back to a host name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getnameinfo()` by wrapping your `struct in_addr` in a `struct sockaddr_in`:

```
int get_host(struct in_addr addr, char *host, size_t hostlen)
{
    struct sockaddr_in sa = { .sin_family = AF_INET, .sin_addr = my_in_addr };

    return getnameinfo(&sa, sizeof sa, host, hostlen, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering OP's original question but using the modern interfaces!

Answer (score 5):

Modern code should not use `struct in_addr` directly, but rather `sockaddr_in`. Even better would be to never directly create or access any kind of `sockaddr` structures at all, and do everything through the `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo` library calls. For example, to lookup a hostname or text-form ip address:

```
struct addrinfo *ai;
if (getaddrinfo("8.8.8.8", 0, 0, &ai)) < 0) goto error;
```

And to get the name (or text-form ip address if it does not reverse-resolve) of an address:

```
if (getnameinfo(ai.ai_addr, ai.ai_addrlen, buf, sizeof buf, 0, 0, 0) < 0) goto error;
```

The only other time I can think of when you might need any `sockaddr` type structures is when using `getpeername` or `getsockname` on a socket, or `recvfrom`. Here you should use `sockaddr_storage` unless you know the address family a priori.

I give this advice for 3 reasons:

1. It's a lot easier doing all of your string-to-address-and-back conversion with these two functions than writing all the cases (to handle lookup failures and trying to parse the address as an ip, etc.) separately.
2. Coding this way makes it trivial to support IPv6 (and potentially other non-IPv4) protocols.
3. The old functions `gethostbyname` and `gethostbyaddr` were actually removed from the latest version of POSIX because they were considered so obsolete/deprecated/broken.

Comment: +1 but that's not how you use [getaddrinfo](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getaddrinfo.html); the last argument is a pointer to pointer to struct addrinfo type. Upon successful return, it must be freed with `freeaddrinfo`.

Comment: @dreamlax: Of course. I left off the `*` declaring `ai`. Fixed it now.

Comment: And as in the other recent question about freeing memory, it's unnecessary and potentially harmful to call `freeaddrinfo` in a program that only performs one lookup (or a small/fixed number of lookups at startup - think of `ping`, `nc`, `wget`, etc.). Freeing the resources is only beneficial in a program that will perform an arbitrarily large number of lookups over its lifetime. Of course a library only making transitory use of the result and returning to the caller will need to free its resources immediately.